# Can't show div on click

Tags: jquery, html

I've searched for an answer but I still don't know where I'm going wrong.

When it's a small screen the menu box appears as it should, everything looks great but when I click it, nothing happens.

This is my code

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#i-nav').click(function() {
    $('nav').toggleClass('show');

  });
});
```

```css
}
nav ul {
  float: right;
  list-style: none
}
nav li {
  display: inline;
  float: left;
  height: 80px;
  margin-right: 20px;
}
nav li a {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  height: 70px;
  line-height: 90px;
  padding: 0px 30px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
nav ul a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #000000;
}
#i-nav {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  right: 30px;
  width: 54px;
  height: 54px;
  background: #ffffff;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000000;
  font-weight: bold;
}
@media (max-width: 950px) {
  nav ul {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 700px) {
  nav ul {
    display: none;
  }
  nav li {
    width: 100%;
  }
  nav li a {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    outline: solid 1px;
    padding: 0px;
  }
  nav li a:hover {
    background: #CCCCCC;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 450px) {
  #logo {
    width: 100%;
  }
  #logo img {
    width: 100%;
  }
  #i-nav {
    top: 100px;
  }
  h1 {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 700px) {
  #i-nav {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text.css" href="style.css">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="main.js"></script>
<title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <div id="logo">
      <img src="img/logo.png" width="300" height="88" alt="" />
    </div>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">1</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">2</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">3</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">4</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <a id="i-nav" href="#">Menu</a> 
  </header>
```

Comment: where is your `show` class defined?

Comment: sorry, you mean in my CSS?.show {
 display: block;
}

Comment: yes, since you are toggling it

Comment: yes it's there I forgot is was at the top of my CSS file ....didn't want to paste the whole thing.

Comment: I thought the issue may be in my linking to jquery library or file but i've checked and it seems right.

Comment: Then there is a problem in your `css`. Since you use `display:none`, make sure that your `show` class handle that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is this part:

```
  nav ul {
    display: none;
  }
```

since you toggle the `.show` class on the `<nav>` element it won't change the fact that your `<ul>` is hidden.

you should either toggle the `.show` class on the `<ul>` or think of some differente CSS approach to it.

Comment: Thank you again, Fred.  Having never used this site I was unaware that you have to do that...